# When using Query Syntax in C# "Enumeration yielded no results". How to retrieve output

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-dataset, linq-query-syntax

I have created this query to fetch some result from database.
[Here is my table structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2896241/how-to-create-query-syntax-for-multiple-datatable-for-implementing-in-operator-of).

What exaclty is happening.

> DtMapGuestDepartment as Table 1
>
> DtDepartment as Table 2
>
> Are being used

```
    var dept_list=  from map in DtMapGuestDepartment.AsEnumerable()
                    where map.Field<Nullable<long>>("GUEST_ID") == DRowGuestPI.Field<Nullable<long>>("PK_GUEST_ID")
                    join 
                    dept in DtDepartment.AsEnumerable()
                    on map.Field<Nullable<long>>("DEPARTMENT_ID") equals dept.Field<Nullable<long>>("DEPARTMENT_ID")
                    select dept.Field<string>("DEPARTMENT_ID");
```

> **I am performing this query on
> DataTables and expect it to return me
> a datatable.**

Here I want to select distinct department from Table 1 as well which will be my next quest. Please answer to that also if possible.

Comment: What happens if you rewrite this as SQL and directly execute it against the database? Does it return results then?

Comment: @Sebastian: Yes, It is returning me desired result set.

Comment: Then I'm afraid you need to profile the query against the database. What is the statement, that is generated and send to the database? Where does it differ from your original SQL query? If you see what Linq2SQL does wrong this could help you to find the error in the query.

Comment: Is this linq2sql or entity framework? It does not look like any linq2sql I have ever used.

Comment: @Sebastain: Do we have some way to track Linq-To-Sql queries, i.e. what each query is resulting in

Comment: @leppie: it is entity framework. not a strongly typed

Comment: @Shantanu, why do you say it's Entity Framework ? The code you posted is Linq to DataSets...

Comment: What is the row count of these tables before you execute the query ? (`DtMapGuestDepartment.Rows.Count`)

Comment: Linqpad (http://www.linqpad.net/) can show you the generated SQL commands, but presumably that wouldn't help if you are querying in-memory objects.

Comment: @sgmoore, Linq to DataSets doesn't generate SQL queries...

Comment: @Thomas, You are of course correct, I have edited my comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

break your query into parts and see which collection has no elements.

```
var mapList = DtMapGuestDepartment.AsEnumerable().ToList();
var deptList = DtDepartment.AsEnumerable().ToList();

var queryResult1 = (
  from map in mapList
  where map.Field<Nullable<long>>("GUEST_ID") ==
    DRowGuestPI.Field<Nullable<long>>("PK_GUEST_ID") 
  select map
).ToList();

var queryResult2 = (
  from map in queryResult1
  join dept in deptList
    on map.Field<Nullable<long>>("DEPARTMENT_ID")
    equals dept.Field<Nullable<long>>("DEPARTMENT_ID") 
  select dept.Field<string>("DEPARTMENT_ID")
).ToList();
```

Comment: Thx for support, although I resolved the problem in the same way u told, but an hour or two before your answer.